# How to keep Date format as is it while sending via REST-json

Tags: json, rest, xmlgregoriancalendar

1. DTO- XDto: private XMLGregorianCalendar date; Set to say 2017-03-22T14:25:30+01:00
2. REST- application/type-JSON, sends above dto as data for say a GET request
3. Output value while testing with Google's ARC- shows something like 1409175049 instead of something like 2017-03-22T14:25:30+01:00

Any idea how to send date as it is rather than json changing it to its own format?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s just sending the date as UTC Epoch. Convert that back to whatever format you want using the Date object.